# SQL Group By Count All Groups

Tags: sql-server

I'm using SQL server but I don't think it should be relevant for this.
My query is far more complex but I'm facing the following challenge:
I want to count the hiring of books grouped by week of hiring, so the table (cleaned up) is like:

```
Name      Week
Book1     1
Book1     1
Book1     2
Book2     2
Book3     1
Book3     1
Book3     2
```

And I need this output:

```
Name          Week        Count
Book1           1          2
Book1           2          1
Book2           1          0  <- Not showing
Book2           2          1
Book3           1          2
Book3           2          1
```

But my query is not showing the count of week 1 of book 2 because it has no events.

Is there any clean way to do it?

Comment: You seem very disturbed by the word "clean" XD. May be that's why you downvoted and didn't read carefully. 
There is no Week13. You can find all weeks with a subquery of distinct weeks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have nodes which might not have any data to contribute to the `count()`, you'll have to identify what those are ahead of time (in your sample case, it looks like you've got combinations of books and weeks). You'll then need to `cross join` them together and this will form the skeleton framework for your query as every possible grouping you want to see, regardless of whether there's data or not. From that manufactured cte/subquery, you can then left join out to your actual data, and you'll get counts of zero for those rows.

so something like

```
;with books (book) as
(
    select 'book1' union all
    select 'book2' union all
    select 'book3'
), weeks (week) as
(
    select 1 union all
    select 2 union all
    select 3
), skelly as
(
    select Book, Week
    from books
    cross join weeks
)
select book, week, count(1)
from skelly
left outer join <sometable>
    on <some join condition>
```

Now obviously I just made that data up. Maybe you have a source you can use to generate that dynamically or othwerise, but that should get you started.

Comment: That's the best approach I've seen. Thanks!